# React prop returns undefined when I pass it to a function and try to access it there

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
//Function
const getThingName = (allCategories, id) => {
  const categoryName = _.find(allCategories, {items: [{id}]}).name;
  return categoryName;
}

//Component
const ThingsListView = ({ allCategories, .... }) => {

  console.log(JSON.stringify(allCategories))

  return (
       <ScrollView>
          <View>
               ...
            {(thingsByUser &&
              thingsByUser.length && (
                <List>
                  {thingsByUser.map(({ id }, idx) => (
                     ...
                    <CardText>{getThingName(allCategories, id)}</CardText>
```

`console.log(JSON.stringify(allCategories))` returns the correct result if I don't make this function call: `getThingName(allCategories, id)`

But when I make this call, `console.log(JSON.stringify(allCategories))` returns undefined.

Strange but true!! My objective is to access the allCategories array value in the getThingName().

Comment: So if you log `allCategories` inside `getThingName` what do you get? undefined? what about logging `id`, do you get the correct value?

Comment: what you're saying is confusing, unless the `_.find` function call is mutating that prop directly somehow (which I doubt but it's possible). The most likely explanation is that `getThingName` is that it is returning undefined because the find function isnt finding anything, perhaps you are passing in the wrong ID maybe its a string and should be a number or vice versa?

Comment: Yes I get correct value for the id inside `getThingName`. But  `undefined` is returned for `allCategories` inside `getThingName`. Now if I comment out the `getThingName` function body and return a hard-coded string, the `allCategories` log returns the correct results. Strange behaviour

Comment: _.find willbe able to mutate the `allCategories` (even if it does so) only if it is a type having data and not an `undefined` type. It returns this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'lodash__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.find(allCategories, { items: [{ id: id }] }).name')`

Comment: Can you, perhaps, make an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io) of your code, so that others can see the full picture?

Comment: I don't know how to emulate my entire mobile app using Expo.Snack. btw I investigated it further and the problem is with the lodash.find

Comment: This piece of code works perfectly fine elsewhere in my code but here it returns undefined:
`const categoryName = _.find(allCategories, {items: [{id}]}).name;`

Comment: Finally I solved it ... I manually iterated the collection as follows:
```_.find(allCategories, function(obj) {
  for (let i=0; i < obj.items.length; i++)
    ...
})```